# Formatting tick_label in kivy_garden.graph from timestamp to strftime

Tags: graph, kivy

I am using a kivy application to show my measurements over time. Currently my time axis is the timestamps of each data point. Is there a way to change the tick_labels of an axis of a kivy_garden.graph to a string-format of the time using e.g. `strftime("%H:%M:%S")` to increase the readability?

Thanks in advance!